# Converting rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has patient information and some values. The patient identifier can be repetitive in a table i.e., there can be multiple records per patientID. Example of the table:

```
ID  Result
1   Positive
1   Negative
2   NULL
2   Negative
2   In-conclusive
3   Negative 
3   Positive
3   
4   Positive
2   Positive
```

I need the above values converted from rows to columns. It should look like below:

```
ID  Result1 Result2 Result3 Result4
1   Positive    Negative        
2   Negative    Inconclusive    Positive    
3   Negative    Positive        
4   Positive
```

Pivot uses aggregate functions to accomplish the task. But I want to use PIVOT without aggregate function. Is that possible?

Can you please tell me how to do it?

TIA,
Sri

Comment: Pivot uses aggregate functions to accomplish the task. But I want to use PIVOT without aggregate function. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use `MIN()`  or  `MAX()` aggregated function. and `row_number()`  to know what column go each value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think using row_number will be a good solution. But I can't quite get my head around how to use row_number to get value to update in columns, Result1, Result2 etc. Can you please explain how this can be done especially when the source table has tens of thousands of records?

Comment: do you know if the max number of result is 4 or is random? if random you may need dynamic pivot instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Well, the maximum number of 'different' results is 4. But when I consider the dataset as a whole it is random.

Comment: Are you ok, if I set the example with max 4 result, even if the data only has 3?

Comment: Yes please. Thanks

Comment: The problem I see is you dont have a column to know what is the order of patient results? I guess ID is patientID? But you should include a date so you know if test were `Positive-Negative` or `Negative-Positive`

Comment: There is a date column in my table and yes the ID is patinetID

Comment: Try this one. http://rextester.com/XQYUH4010 change the `order by` to your date column

Comment: Wow!!! That's great. It works. Thank you very much. Just a final question. Is there a way to put the results of the query into a table?

Comment: Never mind. I have managed to insert the results into a new table.Thanks ever so much for your help